# Как составить правильное предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Пожалуйста, помогите правильно согласовать слова в предложении:

> сертификат на участие мастер класса по керамике

Comment: Это не предложение, а словосочетание.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понимаю, о чем идет речь в вопросе, я бы предложил такой вариант:

> **Сертификат на участие в мастер-классе по керамике**

Answer (score 1):

Правильно так:
**сертификат** (на что?) **на участие** (в чём?) **в мастер-классе** (по чему?) **по керамике.**

Вот пример использования:
Поощрительный приз ― подарочный сертификат на участие в мастер-классе по флористике.

[МАСТЕР-КЛАСС](https://slovar.cc/rus/tolk/49517.html), *м.* [через дефис]
Краткосрочные курсы высшего мастерства в какой-либо области искусства, спорта и т. п., проводимые выдающимися мастерами в своей области.